# Pause, rehome X/Y, resume

Tags: print-quality, homing, layer-shifting

Every now and then I'll have a problem with layer shift. Solving this is a separate issue, but it occurred to me: most of the time when this happens I notice right away because of the noise. What if there were an easy to to pause the print, re-home the X/Y axis (not Z), and then resume. I'd only have one layer that was a bit off. Sometimes that's enough to ruin the print but sometimes I could clean up with a razor knife later and just live with the small scarring and weakness.

Is there a way to do this during a print? I suspect it might require support within the printer (or print tool like OctoPrint), and might also depend on how the print is sliced in terms of knowing absolute vs relative coordinates at any given moment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? It should just work, at least if you're using software like Octoprint to control the printer over serial interface rather than print-from-SD-card on the printer itself. In such a setup you're free to submit whatever commands (in particular, `G28 X Y`) you like while the print is paused. You'll need it setup to save and restore position across pause/resume, or the next command executed might start from the wrong starting position; this would be no problem if it's a travel command, but if it's an extrusion move it would make a mess.

If you're using the printer's builtin pause/resume functionality, I'm not sure whether it will work. It mainly depends on whether it *lets you* access the homing function while paused. If not this is more of a logic limitation than any fundamental incapability, and could be fixed in the firmware.

Comment: It might also be useful to tighten all the belts and try to reduce vibrations/shaking as much as possible to adress the underlaying problem. Is layer shift happening on one axis or both at the same time? Does it happen a little bit on each succesive layer or is everything fine and then you get one big shift?

Answer (score 0):

Repetier software has a Pause button and works very well. I use it to change filament color in mid-print. When pause is invoked manual moves and homing of all three axes are available.
In my case, after pausing I quickly home X and Y so the nozzle is not over the in-progress print in case of oozing during the filament change.  I also move +10 mm on the Z axis to provide a little working space. When resuming, the print head moves to exactly where it was interrupted and goes on as before.
I can't see any reason a pause and home scheme wouldn't be an option after a minor layer shift.